# unable to display captured image in windows phone listview

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to display the captured image in windows phone listview in order to upload using background agent. But when the cameracapturedtask is completing, the app is deactivating in app.xaml.cs. This same functionality is working fine when I upload image from Gallery. I have included my code below. Please help if there is any solution.

```
 private void Camera_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        cmb.Dismiss();
        CameraCaptureTask cameraCapture = new CameraCaptureTask();

        cameraCapture.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(cameraCaptureTask_Completed);
        cameraCapture.Show();

    }



 private void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {

            string filename = e.OriginalFileName;
            var listSplit = filename.Split('\\');
            int i = listSplit.Length;

            string name = listSplit[i - 1];
            PhotoResult photoResult = e;

            j = 1;
            //sendImgRequest(name, e);

            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

            arrfilename.Add(filename);
            //arrimg.Add(bmp);
            arrstream.Add(e.ChosenPhoto);
            arrtext.Add("Photo");

            using (var isostore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {

                var wb = new WriteableBitmap(bmp);
                using (var isoFileStream = isostore.CreateFile(name))
                    wb.SaveJpeg(isoFileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

            }


            newimgdata.Add(new imgdata { image = bmp, text = "Photo", filename = name });
            lstbox.ItemsSource = newimgdata;



        }
    }
```

Comment: Just for interest; put a `try catch` block to encapsulate the whole `cameraCaptureTask_Completed` function inside and check whether the app is still deactivating.